# html get around the noscript tag

Tags: python, html, noscript

I'm using the python library requests to download some webpages and do some parsing after that, eg, get the title of the page. However, it seems requests can't download the source correctly when there's `<noscript>` tag on some webpages.

For example, when trying to get the source of https://www.coursera.org/course/startup, the source I get from requests is different from visiting the page with Chrome. The source requests get is the same with the view source option in Chrome.

So is there any way to "fool" the `<noscript>` tag in some way? Or I need to use something else rather than requests?

Comment: Maybe try faking the `user agent` header to what e.g Chrome is sending?  But you may receive Javascript and while Chrome knows how to run that (e.g to build the page w/Ajax requests &c) Python cannot, so you may need to "mechanize" a browser for the purpose.

Comment: @AlexMartelli I tried to fake user agent and it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

"The source requests get is the same with the view source option in Chrome" ...view source gives you the real html source of the url, same as requests gets. So what you're seeing is what you should expect to see.

Your problem is nothing to do with the `noscript` tag, it's that the content of the page is changed via javascript after loading.

As @alecxe pointed out, you need to look deeper into how the coursera site is built, eg observing XHR requests in the 'Network' tab of Chrome Developer Tools, to see the urls where the actual content you're looking for is loaded from... then you may be able to just load those urls directly with Requests.

Alternatively there is a tutorial here for how to get round the problem of rendering a web page with javascript from python:
https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/

they provide example code that looks like this:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 

#Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://pycoders.com/archive/'  
r = Render(url)  
result = r.frame.toHtml()
#This step is important.Converting QString to Ascii for lxml to process
archive_links = html.fromstring(str(result.toAscii()))
print archive_links
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular page is rendered via a set of asynchronous XHR calls to the Coursera API. Then, the API responses are used to construct the page. This is all done by the browser.

`requests` simply downloads the initial HTML page that, in this case, is basically a container for a lot of other things. `requests` doesn't have a javascript engine built-in, it is not a browser.

Depending on what are you going to do next, you can either automate a real browser (headless or not) with the help of, for example, [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), or, mimic the [API requests](https://tech.coursera.org/app-platform/) being made by the browser - the latter is approach would involve exploring the Coursera API, using browser developer tools to see what API endpoints are used to fill out the page with data.

Example (using `selenium` and `Chrome` browser):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
>>> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
>>> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://www.coursera.org/course/startup')
>>> element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.c-coursePage-header h1")))
>>> element.text
u'Startup Engineering'
```